# maven resources plugin - copy resource

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I had included a maven resources plugin in my pom.xml for copying some resource into a new folder outside the src as per below

```
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-html</id>
                                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/web/</outputDirectory>
                                    <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                                    <resources>
                                        <resource>
                                            <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-docs</directory>
                                            <includes>
                                                <include>api-guide.html</include>
                                            </includes>
                                        </resource>
                                    </resources>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

The issue I am facing now is even though I commented that section, it is still creating that folder web with resources from main and test every time. It seems there is a process running in the background doing that. Can you please help me in resolving this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your project. If you are using eclipse, go to 'file', hover over the drop down menu item that says 'Maven', and then click 'update project'. Then try spinning up, which might update your dependencies from your current pom file version.

Answer (score 0):

I think the folder exists on your disk, though you attempted to take it away from the pom. Right click on that folder and click 'delete', without forgetting to check 'Delete permanently from disk / device'. That will remove that folder from your device, physically. Hope that would resolve this issue